# ios swift making table list keep getting error about nill

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier") as! CustomTableViewCell

     let text = data[indexPath.row]

     cell.label.text = text

     return cell
}
```

above on is the code that I saw to follow.

my code is as below

[image]

I don't know why it getting nil value on 
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locCell")

my storyboard is as below

[image]

I added identifier like below(you can see it on bottom-right section of pic

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the cell for reuse.

```
tableView.register(LocationTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "locCell")
```

Or enter your reuse identifier in the storyboard by selecting your cell and then entering the reuse identifier in the properties to the right.

Comment: It has nothing to do with registering the cell, since the cell is already in table view -as shown in the second screenshot- (not a separated .xib file) there is no need to do such an implementation; It is about being the cell to be *optional*, you could check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808855/5501940).

Comment: A cell needs to have a reuse identifier to be dequeued, adding a cell does not automatically do this

Comment: No Doubt! Assuming that the OP did it from IB builder, however that's not the direct reason for displaying the warning.

Comment: the warning is because `print` takes a any param and its being passed a `UITableVIewCell?`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")` by default is `nil`.

It is the same case for any *optional* when trying to print it out, example:

```
let optionalString: String? = ""
print(optionalString)
```

leads to get:

[image]

So, by declaring a constant as:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
```

since [`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) returns an optional `UITableViewCell` instance, the type of `cell` would be `UITableViewCell?` (optional `UITableViewCell`), that's why you are seeing this error.

**How to get rid of it?**

Assuming that you have set the cell right identifier for your cell:

[image]

Well, in case of having your custom cell, you could cast it as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? MyCustomCell else {
        // something goes wrong
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    print(cell) // it would be fine for now

    // ...

    return cell
}
```

And if you don't have a custom cell, all you have to do is to remove the `as? MyCustomCell` down casting.

Comment: hello :) but it only goes to somethin goes wrong section....even though I added identifier locCell...

Comment: and can't setText like below.

Comment: print("setting tablet value")
        print(cell.name)
        print("------------")
        print(row.name)
       
        cell.name?.text=row.name!

because cell.name is null

Comment: don't get any error message because on above code you wrote, if something goes wrong, it just return. so list table view shown as blank

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locCell")
```

**With this code:**

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locCell", for: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  func  tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
```

NOTE: In your storyboard set tableView Delegate, DataSource and set cell ID cellReuseIdentifier.

Comment: I get error message 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier locCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

why is that? I added locCell identifier on main storyboard...

Comment: i added pic that how I added identifier on storyboard...can you check if it is right? .

Comment: Did you set your UITableViewCell class name  and Cell Id ?